# SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'innerText' of undefined or null reference but works when run through debugger

Tags: javascript

I'm not an experienced javascript programmer so apologies in advance for what is probably a very simple problem.
In the following code I call the akpOpen function to open 2 pop-up windows (IE10), compare the contents of table cells and highlights differences by changing the background color.

```
<script language="javascript">
var nw;
var ow;
function genericOpen(k,n,w,h,t,l) {
 var w = window.open(k, n,
             'width=' + w + ',height=' + h + ',resizable=yes,menubar=0' +
             ',top=' + t + ',left=' + l + ',location=0,toolbar=0' +
             ',scrollbars=1');
 return(w);
}
function checkValues() {
   for (r = 0; r<999; r++) {
      var id = 'r' + r + 'c1';
      if (ow.document.getElementById(id).innerText !=
          nw.document.getElementById(id).innerText) {
          nw.document.getElementById(id).bgColor = 'red';
          ow.document.getElementById(id).bgColor = 'red';
      }
   }
}
function akpOpen(nkey,okey) {
 nw = genericOpen('CNCM0012?KEY=' + nkey, 'w1', 500, 150, 100,80);
 ow = genericOpen('CNCM0012?KEY=' + okey, 'w2', 500, 150, 100,600);
 checkValues();
}
</script>
```

The code works fine if I am loading the pages as static content from my hard drive. If I load the pages from the server which involves a database query and dynamic content I get the following error:
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'innerText' of undefined or null reference 
If I debug the dynamic pages using F12, the code works perfectly.

If I allow the debugger to intercept the error and I view the locals, I can see the 'nw' and 'ow' window handle globals plus their associated elements, and I can find the elements that the getElementById refers to. It seems like a timing issue but I have no experience in this area. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please show an HTML code that calls this function?

Comment: Not sure but worth trying `.innerHTML` instead of `.innerText`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access the content of the windows you're opening dynamically before the windows have had a chance to load. You need to either poll or wait for the window's `load` event to occur.

Using the `load` event is trivial. If you want to poll, the easiest way would be to put an element with a specific `id` value at the end of the response you're generating, then:

```
function checkValues() {
   if (!ow.document.getElementById("marker") ||
       !nw.document.getElementById("marker")) {
       // One or the other is still loading, wait
       setTimeout(checkValues, 100); // Milliseconds
   }
   else {
      for (r = 0; r<999; r++) {
         var id = 'r' + r + 'c1';
         // You might also want to put a guard here in case some of these 'r' elements don't exist
         if (ow.document.getElementById(id).innerText !=
             nw.document.getElementById(id).innerText) {
             nw.document.getElementById(id).bgColor = 'red';
             ow.document.getElementById(id).bgColor = 'red';
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I've been banging my head against this for days. Implemented you solution and it's working perfectly.

Comment: @user2883555: Good deal, glad that helped.